# Audio preferences won't set HDMI as sound output on my mac mini - can this be fixed?

Tags: macos, audio, hdmi

I have a mac mini (mid 2010) osx 10.7.4 with a HDMI output I am using to connect to a television.
The other device I have connected to it (a PS3) has no problem using HDMI to output sound. 
When using system preferences>Sound>Output I can see the device (Name DM2350D,type HDMI), but it won't let me select. Specifically, it lets me select, then automatically switched back to headphones.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved itself by unplugging the headphones.  It seems the os is setup to always prefer the headphones when they are present.